# Еrror-pаge in Spring

Tags: java, spring

good afternoon everyone
my question is banal, but I just can’t find the answer,
I need my custom error page to be thrown for any invalid link

I use Java configuration, not web.хml

i added in application.properties

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

and created controller

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        //do something like logging
        return "error404";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

i used this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

and this not work, can u help me?

Comment: If possible, could you please provide github repo for your sample project so that other can see as a whole and provide you suggestion.

Comment: @Ramsharan https://github.com/berendakova/shelterSpring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment this line in your application.properties file or remove:

```
   #spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

It is wrong information in the article from baeldung.com. ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration should be auto-detected in order to auto register custom ErrorController

**Update for those people who don't believe and downgrade my answer:**
It works!!!

[image]

Comment: Yes, its really works!!!!!! THANK U SO MUCH, U R MY HERO TODAY!

Comment: ooo, thak u a lot!